# Checking non-finite values in Rcpp without creating a vector

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I haven written Rcpp code to perform a calculation related to time series:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double AmiA(arma::vec ts, int n, double cf, double h, double g) {


  double sumA = log(cf);
  double temp;


  for (int i=1; i < n; i++) {
    temp = cf;
    for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {
      temp +=  pow(ts[i]-ts[j]+h, g);

    }
    sumA += log(temp);

  }

  return(sumA);
}
```

Here, "ts" is a vector and "n" is the length of this vector. "cf", "h" and "g" are the constants.

To make the code faster, I declared the double `temp` and then for each observation, I added the portion `pow(ts[i]-ts[j]+h, g)` with it. Now for some observation; the portion `pow(ts[i]-ts[j]+h, g)` gives NaN values. This can be obtained by:

```
n = 100; ts = sort(runif(n)); cf=1.4; h=0.5; g=2.3
AmiA(ts, n, cf, h, g)
# [1] 307.0836
```

How can I check those values without creating a vector and checking the values of this vector? Any ideas will be much appreciated.

Comment: @coatless Here, ts= sort(runif(100)); cf=1.4;  h=0.5;  g=2.3

Comment: @coatless, to produce a reproducible example, I gave that example. But if I get NaN values; how can I check that without creating a vector?

Comment: In terms of `NaN` (not a number), this is triggered if there are missing values in the data or `x` is negative inside `log()`.

Comment: @coatless, are you suggesting to create a vector and filling up each entry and checking if it is giving finite values and then summing up the finite values only?

Comment: You can check the result prior to adding it to the reduction variable, e.g. 

`result = pow(ts[i]-ts[j]+h, g);
if(is_finite(result)) {
    temp += result;
}`

Comment: Again, we need an example of the issue you are running into with the above code related to `NaN` before we can help further. This portion is "unclear"

Comment: @coatless Thanks, that answered my question

Answer (score 3):

In short, you can check for whether a value is finite, e.g. not `NaN`,`Inf`, or `-Inf`, by using `arma::is_finite()`. **Note:** In cases where only *Rcpp* is used, check with `bool finiteness = Rcpp::is_finite(x)[0]` as `Rcpp::is_finite()` returns a `LogicalVector`.

Sample implementation:

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double AmiA(arma::vec ts, int n, double cf, double h, double g) {


    double sumA = log(cf);
    double temp;


    for (int i=1; i < n; i++) {
        temp = cf;
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++) {

            // Compute value
            result = pow(ts[i]-ts[j]+h, g);

            // Guard against non-finite values
            if(arma::is_finite(result)){
                temp +=  result
            }

        }
        sumA += log(temp);

    }

    return(sumA);
}
```